# Should the tag "Fischer" and the tag "Bobby-Fischer" be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Here is the description of the tag "Fischer":

Robert J. Fischer (1943-2008) was an American grandmaster and world chess champion. At the height of his skills (1972) he was peerless. He was known for his meticulous preparation, deep understanding of the game, and mercurial temperament.

Here is the description of the tag "Bobby-Fischer":

Questions related to the American chess grandmaster Bobby Fischer (Robert James Fischer, 1943 – 2008), who became world champion in 1972 and never defended his title.

Am wondering if it is a good idea to combine these two tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're completely right about this.

Given that most of the tags about players (e.g. [kasparov](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kasparov), [karpov](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/karpov), [carlsen](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/carlsen)) only contain their last name, [bobby-fischer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bobby-fischer) should be synonymized into [fischer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fischer). I've proposed a tag synonym [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tags/fischer/synonyms); now we need four users with [score 5 or more in the [fischer] tag](https://chess.stackexchange.com/tags/fischer/topusers) to approve the synonym, or a ♦ moderator.